# Invalid Parameter Error when calling System.Drawing.Image.Save

Tags: c#, reduce, image-size

i am getting Invalid Parameter Error when calling System.Drawing.Image.Save function.
i google and found a few suggestions but nothing works.
what i am trying to do is that, when i upload an image and if it's lager than 100kb i would like to reduce the image size to half. please help.

```
     System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(realpath);


                        FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(realpath);                    
                        int fileSize = (int)new System.IO.FileInfo(realpath).Length;
                        while (fileSize > 100000) //If Larger than 100KB
                        {
                            SaveJpeg(realpath, FullsizeImage);
                            fileSize = (int)new System.IO.FileInfo(realpath).Length;
                        }



 private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        // Get image codecs for all image formats 
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

        // Find the correct image codec 
        for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
            if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
                return codecs[i];
        return null;
    }

    public static void SaveJpeg(string path, Image img)
        {


            Image NewImage = img;
            img.Dispose();

            EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 85L);
            EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

            ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo(GetMimeType(path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('.'), path.Length - path.LastIndexOf('.'))));
//THE ERROR IS HERE!!!!!!
            NewImage.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams); 
//THE ERROR IS HERE!!!!!!

        }




    public static string GetMimeType(string extension)
        {
            if (extension == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("extension");
            }

            if (!extension.StartsWith("."))
            {
                extension = "." + extension;
            }

            switch (extension.ToLower())
            {
                #region Big freaking list of mime types
                // combination of values from Windows 7 Registry and 
                // from C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
                // some added, including .7z and .dat

                case ".323": return "text/h323";

 // more extension here..

                #endregion

                default:
                    // if you have logging, log: "No mime type is registered for extension: " + extension);
                    return "application/octet-stream";
            }
        }
```

EDIT : I modified the code as below, now the image is saving without any exception! Thanks! but another problem here. the file size is not getting reduced. which mean my while loop can never exit. please help and thanks again.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(realpath)))
                    {
                        using (Image FullsizeImage = Image.FromStream(ms))
                        {
                            //code here                           
                            int fileSize = (int)new System.IO.FileInfo(realpath).Length;
                            while (fileSize > 100000) //If Larger than 100KB
                            {
                                SaveJpeg(realpath, FullsizeImage, 85L);
                                fileSize = (int)new System.IO.FileInfo(realpath).Length;
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

Can someone help me please, my problem is not solved yet :(

Answer (score 6):

Because you're disposing an `image` object.

```
public static void SaveJpeg(string path, Image img)
 {
  Image NewImage = img;
  img.Dispose(); <------- Here
  ...
 }
```

EDIT: Method `Image.FromFile` file opens a stream and that file wont be closed till your method is not terminated. Try to use MemoryStream.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(realPath)))
  {
   using (Image img = Image.FromStream(ms))
    {
     ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
     Encoder myEncoder;
     EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
     EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;


     myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
     myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;

     myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

     myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 85L);
     myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
     img.Save(realPath, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Hi AVD, Thanks for the response. but if i remove that line, i am getting this error. A generic error occurred in GDI+

Comment: Because that file is currently opened.

Comment: let me go and modify the program, i will post the update here asap. thanks.

Comment: hi AVD, i edited my post with latest code. no error now and image is saving with the original file size :(